# What is the correct structure for "so that" following multiple purposes?

Tags: sentence-construction, clauses

If I want to say something like:

> They arrived early so that:
>
> 1) their friends could find them easily, and
>
> 2) there were enough good seats to choose.

How can I put them into a sentence without the "1)" and "2)"? I think it is something like

> They arrived early **so that** their friends could find them easily **and so that** there were enough good seats to choose.

But should I say "so that ... and so that ...", or "so that ..., and that", or "so that ... and ..."?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to use the conditional after "so that," so it should be "so that they **wouldn't** miss anything."

The best way to say this is:

> They arrived early so that they wouldn't miss anything and could find good seats.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually, I am more interested in whether a second "so that" is required; and if it is required, what would be the correct way to use it? My example is not good enough, so I will edit it and use a different example with different subjects after "so that".

Comment: I wouldn't repeat "so that" if you can avoid it - it sounds too repetitive. Instead you can make a parallel structure starting from any word after the "so that."

Comment: I see. Thank you so much. My original sentence is much longer so I made up this shorter one just trying to figure out the correct grammar. It would be much better if I can omit the second "so that" even just for brevity.

Comment: Yeah, I would just get rid of the second "so that" in the new sentence. Although now it does sound a bit awkward either way. In general, the longer the parallel parts before and after the "and," the more awkward it will sound.

Comment: Exactly! I feel that my original sentence is awkward because the parallel parts are much longer. I thought it was my grammar issue. So probably I should rephrase it in another way to improve it.